# Where to immediately request data, parse it and save in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to ruby and rails. I'm working on my first app that will parse information from an XML hosted on another server (I was able to do this through net/http). I then need to be able to save that parsed data into my sqlite database as soon as the root of the app is loaded because I'll need access to it.

I'm not entirely sure where I should initiate the parse and immediately save it to my database in order to have it available as soon as the root page loads up. Is this something that should all go in a controller that points to my root index (or should this be handled by a model somewhere)?

If there is a better/faster/more efficient way to access and save this data immediately (as opposed to parsing, seeing if the information in the database is up to date and saving it if not) then I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have be done on every request or only once for the entire app?

Comment: It's using open data from the government - so it's important that the most up to date information is saved as soon as they visit. However, the user will then visit different pages so it would just be a request to the database for every different page they visit.

Comment: It kinda seems to me that the "model/view/controller" paradigm just might be "kinda getting in the way of your thinking" *(so to speak!!)* in this case, because the entire "MVC Paradigm" is really focused upon *"incoming* requests, *to* you."  Which really isn't the case here. What you seem to be looking for is:  "the first clear chance" to *initiate* an asynchronous request to the data-provider.  (My knee-jerk answer would probably be ... `window.onload`.  But there could be tricky timing-concerns here: "you don't yet know that your local (SQLite) data is reliable," until you get the reply!

Comment: Is there maybe a way to pull that information and store it into the database based on a timer (say every 30 mins)? I doubt the data would be updated more than a few times a day (on the provider's end)  so that way I wouldn't have to rely on fetching the information every time someone visits, but rather just have that data parsed, persisted and available before the user even visits?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayed_jobs https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
In your initializer folder create a file that looks like this (this is mine)

```
 Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
 Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2
 Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
 Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
 Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'

if Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs
  begin
    ScheduledWorker.new.schedule
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.info e; Honeybadger.notify e
  end
end

Class ScheduledWorker

  NEXT_RUN_AT = lambda { Chronic.parse("next saturday") }
  MAX_ATTEMPTS = 1

  def max_attempts
    MAX_ATTEMPTS
  end

  def process
  end

  def after
    self.schedule unless Rails.env.test?
  end

  def schedule
    self.class.new.delay(run_at: NEXT_RUN_AT.call).process unless exists?
  end

  private

  def exists?
    Delayed::Job.where("handler like '%#{self.class.name}%'").where(locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil).exists?
   end
end
```